# Item with empty message in git reflog

Tags: git, git-reflog

I've just noticed item in my reflog with empty message. Do you have any idea what could create empty item in log, please?

```
fadea5a HEAD@{6}: merge stable/abc: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
b03c8c7 HEAD@{7}: merge stable/xyz: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
ca6fa32 HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from BRANCH-PER-FEATURE-PREFIX-integration to integration
5c916dd HEAD@{9}:
5c916dd HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from stable_master_14791972220.8707234494009218 to integration
ca6fa32 HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from abz to stable_master_14791972220.8707234494009218
2392d5f HEAD@{12}: reset: moving to HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manually created such items by mistake, by running `git update-ref` with some inappropriate parameters.  I have not seen it created by other Git commands.

These "empty" entries are harmless, so you can just ignore them.